# How to read filenames included into a gz file

Tags: python, gzip, compression

I've tried to read a gz file:

```
with open(os.path.join(storage_path,file), "rb") as gzipfile:
        with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzipfile) as datafile:
            data = datafile.read()
```

It works but I need the filenames and the size of every file included into my gz file.
This code print out the content of the included file into the archive.

How can I read the filenames included into this gz file?

Comment: gzip can only compress a single file. Do you have a gzipped tar archive?

Comment: i've a gz file, but i need to know the file included into the archive and its size

Comment: in this gz file i've a pcap file

Comment: Not actually true, gzip files can contain more than one file called "members".  See the "File format" section of the spec.

Answer (score 8):

The Python `gzip` module does not provide access to that information.

The source code skips over it without ever storing it:

```
if flag & FNAME:
    # Read and discard a null-terminated string containing the filename
    while True:
        s = self.fileobj.read(1)
        if not s or s=='\000':
            break
```

The filename component is optional, not guaranteed to be present (the commandline `gzip -c` decompression option would use the original filename sans `.gz` in that case, I think). The uncompressed filesize is not stored in the header; you can find it in the last four bytes instead.

To read the filename from the header yourself, you'd need to recreate the file header reading code, and *retain* the filename bytes instead. The following function returns that, *plus* the decompressed size:

```
import struct
from gzip import FEXTRA, FNAME

def read_gzip_info(gzipfile):
    gf = gzipfile.fileobj
    pos = gf.tell()

    # Read archive size
    gf.seek(-4, 2)
    size = struct.unpack('<I', gf.read())[0]

    gf.seek(0)
    magic = gf.read(2)
    if magic != '\037\213':
        raise IOError('Not a gzipped file')

    method, flag, mtime = struct.unpack("<BBIxx", gf.read(8))

    if not flag & FNAME:
        # Not stored in the header, use the filename sans .gz
        gf.seek(pos)
        fname = gzipfile.name
        if fname.endswith('.gz'):
            fname = fname[:-3]
        return fname, size

    if flag & FEXTRA:
        # Read & discard the extra field, if present
        gf.read(struct.unpack("<H", gf.read(2)))

    # Read a null-terminated string containing the filename
    fname = []
    while True:
        s = gf.read(1)
        if not s or s=='\000':
            break
        fname.append(s)

    gf.seek(pos)
    return ''.join(fname), size
```

Use the above function with an already-created `gzip.GzipFile` object:

```
filename, size = read_gzip_info(gzipfileobj)
```

Comment: The uncompressed filesize modulo 2^32 is the last four bytes of a "member".

Comment: @PavelAnossov: Yes, I saw your answer just now. :-)

Comment: how to call this method using file path?

Comment: @AhmadDeel the variable `gf` is just a file object open for reading binary. You can create such an object with `open(path, "rb")`. Or just use the gzip module to open a gzip file and pass that object into my function.

Answer (score 3):

GzipFile itself doesn't have this information, but:

1. The file name is (usually) the name of the archive minus the `.gz`
2. If the uncompressed file is smaller than 4G, then the last four bytes of the archive contain the uncompressed size:

```
In [14]: f = open('fuse-ext2-0.0.7.tar.gz')

In [15]: f.seek(-4, 2)

In [16]: import struct

In [17]: r = f.read()

In [18]: struct.unpack('<I', r)[0]
Out[18]: 7106560

In [19]: len(gzip.open('fuse-ext2-0.0.7.tar.gz').read())
Out[19]: 7106560
```

(technically, the last four bytes are the size of the original (uncompressed) input data modulo 2<sup>32</sup> (the ISIZE field in the member trailer, http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html))

Comment: Not actually true.  The gzip file can contain the original filename (see the FNAME flag in the spec).

Comment: The gzip file can, but the GzipFile class doesn't expose it. See Martijn's answer, he has to parse the header himself.

Comment: I see, I didn't read your answer carefully enough; I read that as the gzip file spec doesn't have the information in question.  I apologize for the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

i've solved in this mode:

```
fl = search_files(storage_path)     
for f in fl:
    with open(os.path.join(storage_path,f), "rb") as gzipfile:
        with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzipfile) as datafile:
            data = datafile.read()
        print str(storage_path) + "/" + str(f[:-3]) +  " : " + str(len(data)) + " bytes" #pcap file size
```

i don't know if it's correct.

Any suggest?

Comment: That works, but obviously requires decompression. This can get slow if you have a lot of large files.

Comment: ok, nice observation! now i try with your code posted before! thanks

Answer (score 0):

the new code:

```
fl = search_files(storage_path)     
for f in fl:
    with open(os.path.join(storage_path,f), "rb") as gzipfile:
        #try with module 2^32
        gzipfile.seek(-4,2)
        r = gzipfile.read()
        print str(storage_path) + "/" + str(f[:-3]) +  " : " + str(struct.unpack('<I' ,r)[0]) + " bytes" #dimensione del file pcap
```

Comment: what if user changes the name of gzip file, along with file extension?

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Martjin is really nice, I've packaged it for Python 3.6+: https://github.com/PierreSelim/gzinfo

Juste need to `pip install gzinfo`

in your code

```
import gzinfo

info = gzinfo.read_gz_info('bar.txt.gz')

# info.name is 'foo.txt'
print(info.fname)
```